# List files in the path

Tags: bash, path

I have a function and its first argument is the string with stored path to some directory.
This string is output of the *find . -type d*.

If I list all the files in the current dir, its simple

```
for file in *; do
  commands
done
```

But with the string it doesn't treat it that way of course.

```
for file in "$1"; do
  commands
done
```

So I thought to use *ls*

```
for file in `ls "$1"`; do
  commands
done`
```

But with this solution it simply can't handle the files with space, after some
research I've found everywhere a recommendations to use *find* but I don't get, find will
list all the files/dirs/subdirs, simply the whole tree, but I want just the stuff in the current dir.
I will be very thankful for every help.

**UPDATE**

I've tried one more thing that seems to work:

```
pushd "$1"
for file in *; do
    echo "$file"
done
popd
```

But I would prefer some solution where I don't have to change my working dir

Comment: Now you know why traditionally, Unix did not encourage spaces in file names (though it has always permitted them).  The tools are attuned to work best when there are no spaces (newlines, backspaces, tabs, and other control characters) in the path names.

Comment: Use: `( cd "$1" || exit 1; ...)` because that doesn't leave your main process stranded in a remote directory if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want non-dot files, the following should do the trick.

```
for file in "$1"/*; do
  commands
done
```

More flexible is the following code.

```
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' result; do
    commands
done < <( find -P "$1" -printf %p"\0" )
```

Comment: I suppose that non-dot files are not hidden files so the first example   should do the trick, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

`echo "$str" | while read file ; do echo $file; done`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the recommendations you've read have been to use the `-exec` function of find. You can pass commands to find which will be executed for each file found.

```
$ find . -type d -exec stat {} \;
```

First, note that the characters `{}` will be replaced with name of the file, and you need to escaped the semicolon `\;`.

Also, here is another common Bash idiom that will help you deal with spaces in the files:

```
$ find . -type d | 
while read line; do
    # commands with $line
done;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can manage it, this can be effective:

```
(
cd "$1" || exit 1
for file in *
do
    commands
done
)
```

The parentheses run the contents in a sub-shell.  The sub-shell changes directory to the named directory; then the shell's globbing deals with the file names, including those with spaces.  The primary caveat with that is that if you are executing commands with names relative to the current directory where the shell starts, the `cd` operation breaks everything.  My advice there is "don't execute commands that aren't on your PATH", in which case, that won't be a problem.

Otherwise, review `bash`'s arrays and metacharacter expansions into arrays.  They can handle the task.

Note that `find ... -print0`, usually coupled with `xargs -0` can help.

You can also consider:

```
find "$1" -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec command {} +
```

This provides the file names as proper arguments to `command`, and the `+` notation means 'as many file names as fit conveniently on a command line'.  This has the additional merit over `xargs` of not executing the command when no files are found, and exasperating design (mis-)feature of standard `xargs` (GNU `xargs` has an option to override the standard behaviour, of course).

Comment: Thank for your suggestion, so running the content in a sub-shell is better then the pushd/popd solution I mentioned?
Also I need to return different exit codes depending on the files/folder in the currently processed dir, so in this case should I use export or something like that?

Currently I'm thinking through every possible way mentioned here in the topic, so I was wondering if it is the best solution to change the directory as mentioned here or list the whole path and work with it as Raz posted

Comment: I think Raz's solution is good and simple; I am not sure why I didn't suggest it myself.  Sub-shells tend to be good if you are going to do `cd`; it is embarrassing if your shell can't get back to where it started (which can happen, though permissions need to be pretty weird).  However, they complicate status handling; you'd need to exit the sub-shell with an appropriate status, and then capture it in the parent shell (`estatus=$?`) and decide what to do with it.  Capturing is important; if you execute a command, the status in `$?` will change. Go with Raz's solution; I already upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

There are already rights answers, this is more as a bonus. When I had this problem, I solved it with 'find' printing the file names and saving them into the file. Afterwards, I extracted the file names from the file line by line. Also, many shell commands can be executed with data input data from file.